# IntelliJ IDEA cannot resolve from typesafe maven repository

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, typesafe

I'm migrating a project from sbt to maven which has a dependency on play-json 2.2, its only repository is on typesafe:

http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/

I download the proper repository settings.xml from https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/webapp/mavensettings.html

and install to my .m2 directory, but IDEA cannot connect to it, all artifacts on it are marked as 'ERROR: dependency not found', and settings -> maven -> repositories shows that typesafe repo has an update status of 'error'. Is it because typesafe artifactory server is down? Or it has to be configured by some hidden parameters?[image]

Comment: I have the same problem